# Unzip Command is not working from Java Code

Tags: java, redhat

I am writing a Java code to unzip a zip file in my RedHat env. Please see below:-

```
    String tempRestoreDirPath=/tmp
Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("unzip -o " + tempRestoreDirPath + "/" + "backup_*.zip" + " -d " + tempRestoreDirPath + "/");
    p.waitFor();
```

The unzip command is working fine when there is few files in the zip to unzip.But when there is more than 50 files,the command just hangs and does not proceed.When i check the unzip dir,I can see that it has unzipped first 10 files after that the files are not unzipped.

I think that there is issue with Memory.Can anyone please help me who has faced similar issue.

Comment: Have you tried the same operation from a terminal?

Comment: Yes it works well when executed from Terminal.

Comment: I would suggest building up the string and displaying the string before it is executed, just to confirm it is constructed exactly as you would expect.

Comment: This Question has been answered by me here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40727647/5339816)